# Was bedeutet "Ihr kauft mir den Schneid nicht ab"?

Tags: meaning

Ich verstehe diesen Spruch nicht. Ich bin sogar nicht sicher ob es überhaupt ein Spruch ist.

Könnte mir jemand eklären was er bedeutet? Wenn möglich mit Beispielen.

Ich habe es [hier gelesen:](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/inland/guido-westerwelle-gestorben-zum-tod-des-ex-aussenministers-14132902-p2.html)

Und das ist der Textteil in Frage:

> Fehler, die er anfangs beging, ob
>   im Umgang mit britischen Journalisten oder bei der Zusammensetzung
>   seiner Wirtschaftsdelegation auf ersten Auslandsreisen, wurden ihm
>   ohne Gnade und mit all dem Hohn und Spott des deutschen Mediensystems
>   vorgehalten. Westerwelles trotzige Reaktion **(„Ihr kauft mir den
>   Schneid nicht ab“)** machte ihn in der Folge unempfänglich für
>   berechtigte Kritik: etwa, dass es als Außenminister nicht darum geht,
>   nur so viel über ein Dossier zu wissen, wie für eine fehlerfrei
>   verlaufene Pressekonferenz nötig ist.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schneid

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Die *Schneide* (weiblich) ist der Teil eines Messers oder eines Schwertes, der so scharf geschliffen ist, dass man damit schneiden kann.

In früheren Jahrhunderten war *die Schneide* zumindest in Österreich und im angrenzenden süddeutschen Raum auch ein Synonym für ein Messer, das junge Burschen mit sich führten, um damit gegebenenfalls kämpfen zu können.

Wer *eine Schneid* (das endständige e nach einem Plosiv wird in bairischen Dialekten meist weggelassen) bei sich trug, musste sich also nicht fürchten und konnte sich auch furchtlos einem Kampf mit Rivalen stellen. So ein Bursche »*hatte Schneid*« und war »*schneidig*«.

So wurde aus der scharfen Seite einer Messerklinge ein Synonym für Mut und Draufgängertum. In dieser Bedeutung wechselte das Wort auch sein Geschlecht und wurde männlich: »Der Schneid«.

Diese schneidigen Burschen trugen am Hut Federn (Schwanzfedern von Hähnen, die ja als besonders kampfeslustig gelten), die »*Schneidfedern*« genannt wurden und äußeres Zeichen ihres Draufgängertums waren. Gerieten nämlich zwei dieser Hitzköpfe aneinander, so behielt sich nach dem Kampf der Sieger die Schneidfedern seines Gegners und steckte sie sich selbst an den Hut.

Dadurch sammelten sich auf den Hüten der schlimmsten Raufbolde die meisten Federn an, und wenn jemand mit einem ganzen Federnbuschen am Hut anhob die Fäuste zu schwingen, dann konnte dem Opfer schnell der Mut abhandenkommen. Statt einen aussichtslosen Kampf zu führen, gab so mancher daher seine Schneidfedern lieber gleich her. Man kaufte sich also quasi vom Kampf frei: Man verkaufte seinen Schneid.

Somit war jemand, der sich seinen Schneid abkaufen lies, ein Feigling und Angsthase.

Behauptet hingegen jemand vor einer Auseinandersetzung:

> Ihr werdet mir meinen Schneid nicht abkaufen.

Dann bedeutet das, dass man sich nicht einschüchtern lässt, und vor hat, trotz erwartbarer oder angekündigter Widrigkeiten den gefassten Plan auszuführen.

Answer (score 3):

*Schneid* ist ein Synonym für *Mut,* der aber mit einer gewissen Tapferkeit einhergeht bzw. aufgebracht wird, obwohl man sich der Gefahren/Risiken bewusst ist und es Möglichkeiten gäbe, sich den Gefahren/Risiken zu entziehen. 
So würde man z. B. eher nicht von Schneid sprechen, wenn jemand etwas Mutiges tut, ohne sich der Gefahren/Risiken wirklich bewusst zu sein oder ohne Alternativen zu haben („Mut der Verzweiflung“).

Die Redewendung „den Schneid abkaufen“ bedeutet jemanden „zu entmutigen“ sein Vorhaben umzusetzen. 
Je nach Kontext und Beziehung der Akteure zueinander könnte „jemandem den Schneid abzukaufen“ zwar auch positiv belegt sein, wenn z. B. der Versuch wohlwollend gemeint ist und jemand aus Sorge um den Handelnden auf die Gefahren hinweist, aber das ist eher die Ausnahme und dafür würde man andere Formulierungen bevorzugen. In der Regel ist es negativ in dem Sinne gemeint, dass man sich gegen den Handelnden bzw. dessen Vorhaben stellt.

„Ihr kauft mir den Schneid nicht ab“ ist daher meist (auch in diesem konkreten Fall) als klare Ansage an die Gegner gemeint, dass sie es nicht schaffen werden, ihn zu entmutigen und von seinem Vorhaben abzubringen.